# Why I get a wrong output about Horner's rule in C

Tags: c

f(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>*x + a<sub>2</sub>*x<sup>2</sup>+...+a<sub>n</sub>*x<sup>n</sup>

Firstly I create a dynamic array to store the values of a<sub>n</sub>.
Then I define a function to describe the Horner's rule, but however I change the way of doing output, I just get an enormous number. What's wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int f(int n, int *p, int x);

int main() {
    int *pA;
    int length;
    int x;
    int i;

    printf("input the length of Array:"); ///createArray of 'An'
    scanf("%d", &length);

    printf("please input x = ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    pA = (int *)malloc(4 * length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         printf("input the No.%d element:", i + 1);
         scanf("%d", &pA[i]);    
    }

    printf("%d\n", f(length, pA, x));   ///Horner's rule

    return 0;
}

int f(int n, int *p, int x) {
    int i;
    int pn = p[n - 1];

    for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        pn = p[i - 2] + x * pn;
    }

    return pn;
}
```

Comment: [edit] and show a simple example of input and expected and actual output. Also check if none of your array indices gets out of bounds

Comment: Welcome to SO. The formula mentioned in the question is not what you calculate in your code. It would be better to mention the version you implemented.

Comment: Don't use `4 * length`.  Use `sizeof(int) * length`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the polynomial

```
f(x) = a0 + a1x + a2x2 + ... + anxn
```

The Horner's rule let us evalute it with this formula

```
f(x) = a0 + x(a1 + x(a2 + ... x(an-1 + xan) ... ))
```

We can translate it into a recurrence formula and traverse the array of coefficients backwards.

```
fn = an
fi = ai + x⋅fi + 1
```

Remembering that the actual size of said array would be *n + 1* and that there is a well known idiom used to traverse an array in that way, a possible implementation of the function could be the following.

```
double evaluate_poly_using_horner(size_t n, int const *c, double x)
{
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 0.0;

    double result = c[n - 1];

    for( size_t i = n - 1; (i--) > 0; )
    {
        result = c[i] + x * result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This would solve the problem in OP's code, where the condition `i >= 1` causes the body of the loop to be executed down to `i == 1`, resulting in an access out bounds of the array `p` (`p[i - 2] = ...` becomes `p[-1] = ...`).

Also note that the lines

```
#include <malloc.h>
// ...
int *pA;
// ...
pA = (int *)malloc(4 * length);
//   ^^^^^^^       ^
// ...
```

Could be written as

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// ...
int *pA = malloc((sizeof *pA) * length);
if ( !pA ) {
    // Deal with the failed allocation, maybe exit(1)
}
// ...
free(pA);      // <- Don't leak memory!
```

Comment: It helps me a lot, thank you Bob!